# Indexing Attachment file to elastic search

Tags: indexing, attachment, elasticsearch

I have typed this command to index a document in Elasticsearch

**create an index**

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/test_idx_1x"
```

**create a mapping**

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/test_idx_1x/test_mapping_1x/_mapping" -d '{
  "test_mapping_1x": {
    "properties": {
      "my_attachments": {
        "type": "attachment"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

**index this document**

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test_idx_1x/test_mapping_1x/4' -d '{
  "post_date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
  "message": "test Elastic Search",
  "name": "N1"
}'
```

All these three commands are very goods.
But when I type this command:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test_idx_1x/test_mapping_1x/1' -d '{
  "post_date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
  "message": "trying out Elastic Search",
  "name": "N2",
  "my_attachments": {
    "type": "attachment",
    "_content_type": "text/plain",
    "file": "http://localhost:5984/my_test_couch_db_7/ID2/test.txt"
  }
}'
```

I receive this error message:

```
{
  "error": "NullPointerException[null]",
  "status": 500
}
```

I change it into;

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test_idx_1x/test_mapping_1x/1bis' -d '{
  "post_date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
  "message": "trying out Elastic Search",
  "name": "N2",
  "my_attachments": {
    "type": "attachment",
    "_content_type": "text/plain",
    "_name": "/inf/bd/my_home_directory/test.txt"
  }
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test_idx_1x/test_mapping_1x/1' -d '{
  "post_date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
  "message": "trying out Elastic Search",
  "name": "N2",
  "my_attachments": {
    "file": "http://localhost:5984/my_test_couch_db_7/ID2/test.txt"
  }
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test_idx_1x/test_mapping_1x/1' -d '{
  "post_date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
  "message": "trying out Elastic Search",
  "name": "N2",
  "my_attachments": {
    "file": "http://localhost:5984/my_test_couch_db_7/ID2/test.txt",
    "_content_type": "text/plain"
  }
}'
```

The output is the same error.

I change it like that

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test_idx_1x/test_mapping_1x/1' -d '{
  "user": "kimchy",
  "post_date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
  "message": "trying out Elastic Search",
  "name": "N2",
  "my_attachments": {
    "file": "http://localhost:5984/my_test_couch_db_7/ID2/test.txt",
    "_content_type": "text/plain",
    "content": "... base64 encoded attachment ..."
  }
}'
```

the error is

```
{
  "error": "MapperParsingException[Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character '.' (code 0x2e) in base64 content\n at [Source: [B@159b3; line: 1, column: 241]]; ",
  "status": 400
}

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test_idx_1x/test_mapping_1x/1' -d '{
  "post_date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
  "message": "trying out Elastic Search",
  "name": "N2",
  "my_attachments": "http://localhost:5984/my_test_couch_db_7/ID2/test.txt"
}'
```

I receive this error message:

```
{
  "error": "MapperParsingException[Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('h' (code 104)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@1ae9565; line: 1, column: 132]]; ",
  "status": 400
}
```

if I type

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test_idx_1x/test_mapping_1x/1' -d '{
  "post_date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
  "message": "trying out Elastic Search",
  "name": "N2",
  "my_attachments": "http://localhost:5984/my_test_couch_db_7/ID2/test.txt"
}'
```

I receive error. I can understand it

```
{
  "error": "MapperParsingException[Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character ':' (code 0x3a) in base64 content\n at [Source: [B@1ffb7d4; line: 1, column: 137]]; ",
  "status": 400
}
```

How can I use attach files to ES so that ES can index it?

---

Thanks for your answer. That attachment plugin I have already installed when I type these commands. The content of the text file is encoded in Base64, so I don't encode it anymore. If I don't use the file's path but directly use its contents in Base 64, ex.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test_idx_1x/test_mapping_1x/' -d '{
  "post_date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
  "message": "trying out Elastic Search",
  "name": "N2",
  "my_attachments": "file's content string encoded in base64"
}'
```

all is good, I have already succeeded in posting file and searching its content later.

But if I replace it with path's file, I obtained negative results. So I want to know how to encode Base64 a file in command line,in the command of ES indexing (of course, I don't want to type base64 command to encode a file before typing 2nd command to indexing it in ES). As your answer, do I have to installed something like "Perl library" to execute your command?

Comment: yes you can do. Use a Base64 encoder in whichever language you are programming. I used the command line version because your examples use curl from the command line

Answer (score 4):

http://es-cn.medcl.net/tutorials/2011/07/18/attachment-type-in-action.html

```
#!/bin/sh

coded=`cat fn6742.pdf | perl -MMIME::Base64 -ne 'print encode_base64($_)'`
json="{\"file\":\"${coded}\"}"
echo "$json" > json.file
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/test/attachment/" -d @json.file
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't specify whether you have the `attachment` plugin installed.  If not, you can do so with:

```
./bin/plugin -install mapper-attachments
```

You will need to restart ElasticSearch for it to load the plugin.

Then, as you do above, you map a field to have type `attachment`:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/foo/?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
         "properties" : {
            "file" : {
               "type" : "attachment"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

When you try to index a document, you need to encode the contents of your file in Base64. You could do this on the command line using the `base64` command line utility. However, to be legal JSON, you also need to encode new lines, which you can do by piping the output from `base64` through Perl:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/foo/doc?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "file" : '`base64 /path/to/file | perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g'`'
}
'
```

Now you can search your file:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/foo/doc/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "text" : {
         "file" : "text to look for"
      }
   }
}
'
```

See [ElasticSearch attachment type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/attachment-type.html) for more.

Comment: When I type your command:
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test_idx_1x/test_mapping_1x/1bis4' -d '{ "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12", "message" : "trying out Elastic Search", "name" : "N2","my_attachments" : '`base64 /inf/bd/tran_chi/test4.txt | perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g'`'}'

I have already received this message:
{"error":"MapperParsingException[Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('T' (code 84)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@8aeedc; line: 1, column: 134]]; ","status":400}

Comment: At this moment, I must always encode the file's content in Base64 using base64 command before. Then I type 2nd commnand in order to post this base64-encoded content to the field my_attachment in Elastic search.

I don't know how to type only one command in command line to index the attachement in ES.

Thanks you anyway

Comment: I am getting ```-bash: /usr/bin/curl: Argument list too long``` error when trying to run the post command. ```curl``` command is treating text in single quotes ```'``` as two different arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete shell script implementation:

```
file_path='/path/to/file'
file=$(base64 $file_path | perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g')
curl -XPUT "http://eshost.com:9200/index/type/" -d '{
    "file" : "content" : "'$file'"
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative solution - plugin at http://elasticwarehouse.org. You can upload binary file using _ewupload?, read newly generated ID and update your different index with this reference.

Install plugin:

```
plugin -install elasticwarehouseplugin -u http://elasticwarehouse.org/elasticwarehouse/elasticsearch-elasticwarehouseplugin-1.2.2-1.7.0-with-dependencies.zip
```

Restart cluster, then:

```
curl -XPOST "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_ewupload?folder=/myfolder&filename=mybinaryfile.bin" --data-binary @mybinaryfile.bin
```

Sample response:

```
{"id":"nWvrczBcSEywHRBBBwfy2g","version":1,"created":true}
```