# How to test elasticsearch for a flat file using curl?

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I have installed elasticsearch & curl successfully and is working fine, means

```
http://[localhost]:9200 & curl -XGET [localhost]:9200'`  results in 

{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Bereet",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.0.1",
    "build_hash" : "5c03844e1978e5cc924dab2a423dc63ce881c42b",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-02-25T15:52:53Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.6"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Now i want to run the search for a file called x.java, i have set path.logs: [fully qualified path for x.java]

What else i need to do, to start searching something using elasticsearch? I have installed JSON plug-in in Mozilla.

Could anyone please help me understand how to run the elasticsearch against my specified file? Thanks in Advance

Comment: you want to search inside file or search for a file 
???

Comment: @Sidharthan  Actually i just started with elasticsearch, so inside a file i am trting to search for string

Comment: i don know why you specified path.logs : path of a file.It will use that file to store ES logs...how you indexed a java file in ES.Please share the mapping of your index..

Comment: Actually i did not map any index. Could you please point me to a simple tutorial to understand all this, i need it step by step only for flat file and only using elasticsearch,curl & Json

Comment: can you please tel me what is you requirement?? you wanna search in a file or you wanna search in files in a folder??

Comment: Please guide me to search in a file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111743/indexing-attachment-file-to-elastic-search refer this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50024/discussion-between-rajesh-and-sidharthan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: http://joelabrahamsson.com/elasticsearch-101/

Elasticsearch does not search external data, only what you put into it. Adding data to ES is called indexing, and everything you add is a document. So you should first index your file:

```
POST <index_name>/<type_name>/<document_id> {
    "name": "<file_name>",
    "content" : "<file_contents>",
    ...
    "<any other fields you want to store>": "<any other values>"
}
```

Comment: Using curl i need to set the index. Right? Or i have to put this somewhere in ES? What configuration file i need to change? What parameter i need to set in elasticsearch.yml?

Comment: Install this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense/doinijnbnggojdlcjifpdckfokbbfpbo?hl=en It'll let you send commands to ES manually. For a quick start you dont need to change any config.

Comment: I'm having trouble installing sense as it says moved to elasticsearch\marvel... and from there i am not able to download marvel!!!